# Is it possible to locally set a length in an environment?

Tags: environments, exam

I write a lot of documents using the `exam` class. A typical document of mine looks like this:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\setlength{\marginpointssep}{2.5cm}%

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question Answer the following.
  \begin{parts}\setlength{\marginpointssep}{.05cm}%
  \part[10] First question.
  \part[10] Second question.
  \end{parts}\setlength{\marginpointssep}{2.5cm}%

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Notice that outside the `parts` environment, the value of `\marginpointssep` is `2.5cm`. Inside the `parts` environment, the value of `\marginpointssep` is `.05cm`.

Is it possible to accomplish this automatically, so that `\marginpointssep` is `2.5cm` outside of every `parts` environment and `.05cm` inside every parts environment?

Comment: Why forcing people to guess how `\marginpointssep` should influence the result if you don't add clues about it?

Comment: @egreg I thought that the question was likely answerable with this minimal context. Given the two excellent answers below, it looks like I was correct.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick It would have been great if your example would a) have included `\pointsinmargin` and b) had a value for `marginpointssep` that would have been visible inside the margins. Changing the length automatically had been a matter of seconds, but finding out how to see if it works took much longer and involved reading the documentation of the `exam` class.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick Not sure if you can see the edit history of my answer, but it took me nearly 10 minutes to find out how to actually display points in the margin - I bet it would have taken you much less time to include this command in your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- to add `\setlength{\marginpointssep}{.05cm}` to the `parts` environment one can use the `etoolbox` package
- resetting the length to 2.5cm after the `parts` environment is unnecessary as the change happened within a group, so only the content inside the `parts` environment is affected by this change.

---

```
\documentclass{exam}

\setlength{\marginpointssep}{1.5cm}%

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{parts}{\setlength{\marginpointssep}{.05cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \pointsinmargin

    \question Answer the following.
      \begin{parts}
            \part[10] First question.
        \part[10] Second question.
    \end{parts}%
  
    \question[15]

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might explain the concept of grouping, that the change of length is local to the environment because it is already in a group.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about 2.5cm, which under normal circumstances will push the points past the left margin of the paper.

Use `\partshook`:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\pointsinmargin

\setlength{\marginpointssep}{1.5cm}
\renewcommand{\partshook}{\setlength{\marginpointssep}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question[20] Answer the following.
  \begin{parts}
  \part[10] First question.
  \part[10] Second question.
  \end{parts}

\question[20] Answer the following.
  \begin{parts}
  \part[10] First question.
  \part[10] Second question.
  \end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]